# R clValid function Error for huge dataset

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate my clustering results using this package
I run the following but it is giving me error;

```
intern <- clValid(test_clvalid, 3:25, maxitems = 260000, clMethods="kmeans", validation="internal")
Error in hclust(Dist, method) : size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536
```

test_clvalid is my data set, it has 256342 observations with 5 numeric variables.

When I ran the same with less data observations, it seems to run fine. Not sure why hclust() is called/giving error when I specify to use k-means evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that package is using `hclust` to initialize the input to `kmeans`,
as you can see [here](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-internal.R#L46).
That also means that,
[before that](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-functions.R#L100),
the cross-distance matrix was calculated,
which has `256,342 x 256,342` dimensions for your whole dataset.
The `hclust` function is hard-coded to deal with matrices that are `65536 x 65536` at the most,
so you won't be able to use that package to evaluate k-means on your data.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. That's sad news. This package had good comparison metrics and plots. Do you know any similar package that could work with this data size or more. I tried [clusterCrit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusterCrit/index.html) but it is very slow for only one metric.

Comment: I encourage you to look at the source code, I'm fairly certain you can call `kmeans` directly on your data to avoid the call to `hclust`, and you can see how it calculates some validity indices [starting here](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-functions.R#L250). It also uses `cluster::silhouette`. You might be able to replicate its functionality.